# How to get users location statically and use it in other classes iOS?

Tags: ios, swift2, uilabel, swift3, core-location

I want to separate user's location methods to LocationUtils so that I can use them  and do not have keep writing the duplicate methods but I am struggling to do that, is there a resources I can learn ? I am new to iOS.

```
class LocationUtils: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  var userCity: String?

  func enableLocationServices() {
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
      locationManager.delegate = self // Comment
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    self.locationManager.requestLocation()
  }


  // Try ro call this statically
  func getUsersClosestCity(lat: CLLocationDegrees, lng: CLLocationDegrees){
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) {
      (placemarks, error) -> Void in

      let placeArray = placemarks as [CLPlacemark]!
      var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
      // Can the array throw an exception
      placeMark = placeArray?[0]
      if (placeMark != nil) {
       //userCity = placeMark.addressDictionary?["City"] as? String?
        self.userCity = placeMark.addressDictionary?["City"] as? String

      }

    }

  }
  func getUserCity() -> String? {
    return self.userCity
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    self.getUsersClosestCity(lat: locValue.latitude, lng: locValue.longitude)
  }

}
```

Now I want to use these methods in various classes in the project

that's how I used it

```
override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()
    setLocationView()

  }





 func setLocationView() {
    let locationLabel : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/3, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, width: 500, height: 21))
    let locationLabelFrame = CGRect(x : UIScreen.main.bounds.width/4, y: 3 * (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/4), width : 125, height : 45)
    locationLabel.frame = locationLabelFrame
    locationLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    let locUtil = LocationUtils()
    locUtil.enableLocationServices()
    if (locUtil.getUserCity() != nil) {
      locationLabel.text = locUtil.getUserCity()
    }

    self.view.addSubview(locationLabel)
  }
```

this does not add UILabel to the view, When I remove the location related calls, I get a label on the view

I would appreciate if anybody can guide me resources I can learn or any tips on this how to do

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make a singleton location service that can he used by all of your viewControllers:

```
class LocationReportingService {
    static let shared = LocationReportingService()
    fileprivate let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    func beginMonitoring() {
        //insert logic here
    }
}
```

To use it you call LocationReportingService.shared.beginMonitoring().  You can add properties for las know location and also broadcast events with NotificationCenter.default.post that your other view controllers can listen for.